# Flutter - отображение только части SliverAppBar в сложенном состоянии

Tags: flutter

Есть расширяемый SliverAppBar. Как сделать, чтобы в сложенном состоянии отображался не весь SliverAppBar, а только leading (стрелочка NavigateUp) как на изображении ниже?

[image: Отображается только часть с leading]

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно (Можно посмотреть в [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)):

```
SliverAppBar(pinned: true, ...)
```

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Go!'),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Bar())),
    );
  }
}

class Bar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    centerTitle: true,
                    title: Text("Title"),
                    background: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Body"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Вы неправильно меня поняли. Нужно не чтобы SliverAppBar не убирался, а чтобы в сложенном состоянии он был как бы обрезанным, чтобы занимал не всю ширину, а лишь, скажем, 32dp, и в правом нижнем углу был закруглён.

Comment: @Эдгар теперь понял, вам придется переписывать SliverAppBar в своей реализации. [Статья по этой теме](https://habr.com/ru/post/456054/). Насколько я знаю, SliverAppBar не даст просто так изменить свою ширину, только высоту.